# JavaScript, Dom Events, Dom Manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I know how to create a shopping list but I have problems with deleting items from that list when something is done! Can you please show me how to do it with a simple code example?
I mean: if i have to buy Pasta, Chocolate, Oil and Milk and I bought the Pasta, how cand I create a button next to Pasta to click on and delete Pasta from the list?

I tried to use the removeParent but I don't know enough about it, can you explain it to me?

Comment: Explore the myriads of To-do examples in JavaScript you can find online, create some code, then when you're stuck, create a [mcve]. Please read [ask].

Comment: What does your list look like?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const shoppingList = ['Pasta', 'Chocolate', 'Oil', 'Milk']

shoppingList.splice(shoppingList.indexOf('Oil'), 1)

console.log(shoppingList)
```